# SmartGit Conflict Errors on Imported Classes

Tags: php, git, merge, conflict, smartgit

Start this off by saying: yes I know our version control is crap right now. I'm just dealing with what we got for now.
I'm using SmartGit and language is PHP 7.3

TLDR; SmartGit thinks two classes I imported conflict with another branch when I try to merge. But they are just two classes I added on my branch for my code to work. What is the conflict?

I've been running into some odd merge issues. This on in particular is really bothering me
I pulled the branch I'm working off of as a base 'prod' and created a new branch called LMS-446 etc
I did my work on it. Since my work was completed, there have been some changes made to the base branch 'prod' that I want to pull into my branch so when we implement my work onto the prod branch, it removes conflicts that need resolved. So, I checkout 'prod', I pull changes on prod then check out my branch 'LMS-446', right click on 'prod' and select Merge. There is one conflict that comes up. When working on my branch I imported Exception and stdClass into my branch (something that's done in other classes without issue) and the conflict is 'prod' doesn't have those imports...
To me this is like 'duh. yes it doesn't have those classes... because they were added with my code. Can we just add them?'
Image of the issue at hand
[image]

So I select Take Left,Right. So it will take my version that adds the imports, and takes whatever 'prod' has in attempts to please the conflict gods.

Out of sanity sake, I try to merge 'prod' back into 'LMS-446' thinking that I resolved the conflict so it should pass without issue. Nope. Conflict again, the same exact imported classes, same exact line. I've no idea what the issue with those lines are. I've tried removing them and adding them back. They work on my tests. There is nothing wrong with the code and yet SmartGit thinks there is a conflict.

Anyone familiar with this? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you follow the Log of the conflicting file can you see some activity in the conflicted area in concurrent branches? Maybe some additions and removals of imports at this place which finally end up with the same content?

A few times I have seen such conflicts, too. In this case, I have ignored what Git thinks but resolved in a way that the file looks correct to me, everything compiles, tests run ...

Also note, that this is rather a Git than SmartGit issue.